# How can I search only for parts of values inside the mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some paths in my SQL database:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|                  path                   |
+-----------------------------------------+
| monkey/rabbit/horse/bird/cat            |
| monkey/rabbit/horse/sheep               |
| monkey rabbit/frog/mouse                |
| monkey rabbit/frog/mouse/horse/elephant |
| monkey rabbit/frog/mouse/horse/raccoon  |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I want to search if a specific value exists.

```
$srch = "horse";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM farm WHERE id = ? AND path LIKE '%{$srch}%'";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute([$id]);
$srch_arr = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "Search result: ".count($srch_arr);
```

As a result, for me the only interesting part is the path until the searched value:

```
foreach ($srch_arr as $key => $val) {
$subject = $val['path'];
$pos = strpos($subject, $srch);
if ($pos !== false) {
    $result = substr($subject, 0, strpos($subject, '/', $pos));
}
echo $result;
}
```

My result is now:

```
Search result: 4

monkey/rabbit/horse
monkey/rabbit/horse
monkey/rabbit/frog/mouse/horse
monkey/rabbit/frog/mouse/horse
```

But actually the result I need in this case is:

```
Search result: 2

monkey/rabbit/horse
monkey/rabbit/frog/mouse/horse
```

Comment: There are multiple rows so the result comes 2, if you want 1 then you need to `LIMIT` here.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Thank you, I will check this out

Comment: @FrayneKonok The `LIMIT` solution is unfortunately not working for me. Updated my question to be more clear

Comment: You could push `$result` to an array, then use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove the duplicates.

Comment: there is four `horse`, what is the mechanism that you got 2????

Comment: check this [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e0c36/2)

Comment: @FrayneKonok: The mechanism is that it is the same folder, so I do not need to display it twice

Comment: Hi Jarla, did you get everything working OK or would you like some more assistance with your code? : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for updating the question. Try updating your SQL to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT left(path,instr(details,"{$srch}")+CHAR_LENGTH("{$srch}")) AS 'path' FROM `farm` WHERE id = ? AND `path` LIKE '%{$srch}%'
```

This will process the results and cut the path on the SQL side which means less processing is required on the PHP side. This means you can remove your substr function.

Below is a test results screenshot that shows you it working in MySQL.

Please let me know if any more info is required. : )

[image: Test Results Screenshot]

Comment: I updated my question to demonstrate, that your solution is not working for me

Comment: In my code its not working, cannot figure out why, I need more time to solve it

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but I'd need more coffee than the day has so far allowed...

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(path,1,LOCATE('/horse',path)+LENGTH('/horse')) path 
           FROM farm
          WHERE path LIKE '%horse%';
```

Comment: @jarla, this query is for you. This is perfect to your mechanism.

Comment: Something is not working, I still get 4 results, I wrote it exactly `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(path,1,LOCATE('/{$srch}',path)+LENGTH('/{$srch}')) path FROM farm WHERE id = ? AND path LIKE '%{$srch}%'";`

Comment: '/' is part of $srch

Answer (score 0):

mmm , from PHP side you can do something like this , push your values to an array if they are not existing already.

```
$final = array();
foreach ($srch_arr as $key => $val) {
   $subject = $val['path'];
   $pos = strpos($subject, $srch);
   if ($pos !== false) {
     $result = substr($subject, 0, strpos($subject, '/', $pos));  
     if (!in_array($result,$final)) {   
        $final[] = $result;
     }
   }
}

print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [**`array_unique()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function to remove the duplicate values. Something like this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($srch_arr as $key => $val) {
  $subject = $val['path'];
  $pos = strpos($subject, $srch);
  if ($pos !== false) {
    $result = substr($subject, 0, strpos($subject, '/', $pos));
    array_push($arr, $result);
  }
}

$uniqueArr = array_unique($arr);
print_r($uniqueArr);

//Or simply print_r(array_unique($arr));
```